# android MediaPlayer setDataSource not grabbing a playable file

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Hey I'm having trouble getting a stream to play from my localhost server (and also other websites with raw mp3 files). My code work for the site that is commented out so i assume it has something to 
do with the server and not the java code.

```js
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
 //static final String ANCHOR = "http://www.hrupin.com/wp-content/uploads/mp3/testsong_20_sec.mp3";
 static final String ANCHOR = "http://spintron.ddns.net/Random%20Access%20Memories/07%20-%20Touch.mp3";
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setVolume(1, 1);
        try{
         mp.setDataSource(ANCHOR);
         mp.prepareAsync();
        }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Prepared",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mp.start();
    
   }
  });
        
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: @spinton URL may be wrong or refer this https://github.com/protocol10/SangeetPlayer/blob/master/src/com/akshay/sangeetplayer/net/StreamInput.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To play music file refer below code.
my res/raw folder contains options_music.wav music file.

```
// Play Music

    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    AssetFileDescriptor descriptor;


    try {
        descriptor = getAssets().openFd("options_music.wav");
        mp.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        descriptor.close();
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();

        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //Log.e("Music", "Music Completed........");
                mp.start();
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ErrorMusic", "Cant Play Music File"+e);
    }
```

For your url , make sure your it is properly url encoded and accessible from your mobile.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. i believe that my problem is as a result of a port forwarding problem.